# JSON.NET Parse with JObject, JToken and JArray

Tags: json, parsing, json.net

I have a json string that i'm trying to parse with JSON.net, i want to loop and use the names in the `komponent` array. This is my json string:

```
{"Name": "Service","jsonTEMPLATE": "{"komponent": [{"name": "aa"}, {"name": "bb"}]}"}
```

This is my code using JSON.net

```
    JObject o = JObject.Parse(serviceData);
    JToken j = (JToken)o.SelectToken("jsonTEMPLATE");
    JArray a = (JArray)j.SelectToken("komponent");

    foreach (JObject obj in a)
    {
        //Do something
    }
```

i get `null` from `(JArray)j.SelectToken("komponent");`

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid.  You can run it through [JSONLint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) to check it.  You have quotes around the value of the `jsonTEMPLATE` property, which should not be there if it is to interpretted as an object:

```
{
    "Name": "Service",
    "jsonTEMPLATE": "{"komponent": [{"name": "aa"}, {"name": "bb"}]}"
}
```

The JSON needs to look like this for your code to succeed:

```
{
    "Name": "Service",
    "jsonTEMPLATE": {"komponent": [{"name": "aa"}, {"name": "bb"}]}
}
```